# How to determine error if using $.post() or $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

I would like to know how to handle errors for 
$.post or $.get

```
$.post(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
$.get(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType)
```

without using $.ajax which has an error handler.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: $(this).attr("method"),
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (data, status)
    {

    },
    error: function (xhr, desc, err)
    {


    }
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `post` and `get` are promisses, so you can chain the functions `done`, `fail` and `always` on these:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
    alert("success");
})
.done(function() {
    alert("second success");
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("error");
})
.always(function() {
    alert("finished");
});
```

Or even later, by a varibale:

```
jqxhr.always(function() {
    alert("second finished");
});
```

[See the documentation.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)